# How can I disable animation from Up navigation?

Tags: android, navigation, toolbar

I have a Restaurants parent activity and a Menu child activity. I've implemented Up navigation from Menu to Restaurant. I'm trying to get rid of the Menu activity's exit animation (slides down). I've only been able to find help on using custom animations using `overridePendingTransition()`. I've tried using `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` for no animation, but the child activity still animates. I've tried using `NavUtils` methods requiring intent arguments and adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` to the intent, but that didn't work either. Does anyone know of a way to go back to the parent activity with no animation?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)). `overridePendingTransition()` has to be called IMMEDIATELY after the statement calling the next activity. In the case of using Up navigation, immediately after calling `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);`. Using `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` rids of any animation.